# Total TLAB Size vs Total Object Size in Java Mission Control

Tags: java, memory-management

I am looking into Oracle Java Mission Control for memory consumption investigation. To get started I used the Flight Recording *wldf.jfr* provided in the JDK 8 samples. I am puzzled about the columns *Total TLAB Size* vs *Total Object Size*:

[image: Flight Recording] 
For the first thread, the *Total Object Size* is 1.52MB, but the *Total TLAB Size* is 809.91MB (different magnitude). How is this explained? The application was executed using

**-Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m**

My understanding until now is that each thread has a single TLAB. A TLAB  can be retired and a new one is allocated for the thread based (among other factors) on the value of

**-XX:TLABWasteTargetPercent**

The data of the retired TLAB remain in Eden and their fate is decided on the next Minor GC. Is then the column *TLABs* referring to the total number retirement/allocations? This in turn should suggest that *Total TLAB Size*, is a cumulative measure of these allocations of new TLABs.

Can I extract any conclusions on the memory management? Maybe too many TLAB allocations could suggest increasing the size of TLAB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Allocation in new TLAB' event is a bit tricky,
it represents one object allocation, which is causing a new TLAB to be allocated for the thread. (That TLAB is heuristically assumed to contain only objects of the same type as the first object)
The event contains information both about the object allocation itself, and about the TLAB.

The 'Total Object Size' column (not enabled by default), just sums the object sizes for the individual objects causing the new TLABS, so it's quite a weird statistic really.

In JMC 6, included in JDK 9, I believe we have removed this particular calculation.